# AES CTR Test Vectors

Tags: encryption, openssl, testing, aes, vector

I am implementing a small demo application which encrypts using AES CTR with OpenSSL is it possible to test the algorithm using different modes of operation test vectors for example testing the ECB vector in my application and check the result or is it restricted to ctr test vectors??? If it is restricted to test it with ctr can anybody provide me the ctr test vectors??? Many Thanks!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[NIST Special Pub 800-38A](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-38a.pdf) has test vectors for several modes of AES including CTR mode.